# gdb cannot access memory from string address

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86

I compiled an assembly program with the following variables:

```
.data
x: .long 1337
str: .string "Hallo Welt\n"
```

In gdb I wanted to use the examine command with the str address.

```
(gdb) x str
0x6c6c6148: Cannot access memory at address 0x6c6c6148
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0x6c6c6148 is 'Hall' so gdb is trying to interpret the string contents as an address. From [the manual](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_56.html):

> *addr*, starting display address
>   *addr* is the address where you want GDB
>   to begin displaying memory. The expression need not have a pointer
>   value (though it may); **it is always interpreted as an integer address
>   of a byte of memory.**

Try `x/s &str`, it might work better.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought str is an address itself like char* strings in C.